# The pgAdmin 4. ImportError: DLL load failed while importing unicodedata: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

When running `pgAdmni4` from `PostgreSQL` it throws an error. Know how to fix it?

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\Jonatan\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\Jonatan\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_4600_LIWMILTQIFEJKYVB
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: JONATAN-PC
  - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  - FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: NO
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\Jonatan
  - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\Jonatan\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\JONATAN-PC
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 2
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 7779c6c3-3251-4a31-b350-3d7c6c48dc25
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 49444
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 1706
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SESSIONNAME: Console
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - TEMP: C:\Users\Jonatan\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\Jonatan\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: Jonatan-PC
  - USERNAME: Jonatan
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\Jonatan
  - windir: C:\Windows
  - windows_tracing_flags: 3
  - windows_tracing_logfile: C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
--------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 39, in <module>
    import config
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .environment import Environment
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .lexer import get_lexer
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\lexer.py", line 46, in <module>
    compile("f��", "<unknown>", "eval")
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing unicodedata: The parameter is incorrect.
```

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve a similar error on windows 7 64 bits by installing the windows update "KB3063858" and then reinstalling pgadmin, can download it from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47442
It supercedes the update "KB2533623", so that one should also work

(Got the hint from this site: https://windowsquestions.com/2021/10/01/the-pgadmin-4-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-unicodedata-the-parameter-is-incorrect/)